# Log4j Manual Configuration with Java Properties

Tags: java, configuration, log4j

I'm trying to load log4j.properties(*mylog4j.properties*) file manually in Spring web application. The file is located under */WEB-INF/* and I'm reading this file in SYPLogger class as seen below:

```
private static final String CONF_FILE_NAME = "mylog4j.properties";             
Properties props = new Properties();
props.load(new FileInputStream(CONF_FILE_NAME));
PropertyConfigurator.configure(props);
```

[image: Project File Explorer]

Although I tried different location, I couldn't read the file. When I gave full path of the configuration file, everything is ok. But the above code gives FileNotFoundException(The system cannot find the file specified). 
Please help.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with the next:

```
String path = Thread.currentThread()
                    .getContextClassLoader()
                    .getResource("/")
                    .toURI()
                    .resolve("../mylog4j.properties")
                    .getPath();
Properties props = new Properties();
props.load(new FileInputStream(path));
PropertyConfigurator.configure(props);
```

In another way, have you seen the class [`org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.4.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/util/Log4jConfigListener.html). You can configure this listener in the `web.xml` file. e.g.:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/mylog4j.properties</param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>
```

Comment: Thanks. I was looking for the first solution.